# Error when installing a managed Beta package on a DE Sandbox

Tags: apex, security-review

The description of a managed beta package reads: "use to test and validate this package internally and with selected customers before release. Note: this type of package can only be installed in Developer Edition, sandbox organizations, or testing organizations for registered partners."

However, we're trying to install a managed beta package in a Professional Edition Sandbox (the sandbox type is "Developer"). Shouldn't this work based on the description above?

We're getting an error "Installing this package requires the following feature and it's associated permissions: Apex Classes"

I know PE doesn't support running Apex unless it's from a managed package in the ISV force program that's gone through security review - but shouldn't the Managed Beta package work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can spin a professional edition org from your partner portal org and you can test the BETA package .The assumption is you are registered partner .

Please see the below Idea and the comment from the Product Manager claiming its been [delivered](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BovZAAS) .

Obviously you cannot do the testing in customer org .So make sure by contacting SFDC that you are a registered partner .

Also its worth noting that now you cannot create orgs from partner portal while you still can create an org from environment hub .Use environment hub to create the professional edition org .